# After what amount of time is the API guaranteed to return a new post?

Tags: support, api

Sometimes, right after a question or an answer has been posted, the Stack Exchange API will not reflect this fact until after a few seconds. I'm currently working on a thingy that finds spam in new questions and answers, and this is kind of a brick wall since many questions and answers aren't being returned by the API. I've also noticed this issue in the Android app, where after posting a question it claims my own question does not exist.

What is the minimum amount of time I have to wait before asking the API for a newly posted post?

See also: http://shouldiblamecaching.com

Comment: My best guess is: one minute.

Comment: This also affects the web sockets. Once upon a time (several times a day, actually) a question doesn't make it to the realtime socket. And per-site sockets get frames with empty bodies for the same questions.

Comment: [It's getting worse](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/305585/350567).