# Post data isn't available in the API until several minutes after post creation

Tags: feature-request, bug, status-completed, api

For a long time, the API has had data about a post almost immediately after it was posted (I'm talking sub-5-seconds here). Recently, that behaviour has regressed, and the API doesn't have data about a post until several minutes after the post was created.

We've discovered this via SmokeDetector, which reads all new posts coming into the network. The Smokey codebase waits 3 seconds after detecting a new post to ensure that the API has data for it; this approach has worked for the past 3 years. Recently, we've [been](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/42194012#42194012) [seeing](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/42193525#42193525) Smokey unable to find data in the API, even after the 3-second wait. This has been happening since about Monday this week.

If this is a regression, and the API *should* have data immediately, then this post is a [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) report.

If this was an intentional change, then this post is a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request): please can we restore the old behaviour? Not having data available in the API promptly is preventing Smokey being able to detect spam quickly, and in some cases is resulting in spam being missed entirely.

Comment: It might be neither, but rather that the spammers are using a [caching trick](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/305590/api-cache-behavior-can-be-exploited-to-hide-posts-from-api-clients?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: Interesting enough, when trying it [here](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/answers-by-ids) there appears to be no cache.

Comment: One of our devs started working on this and the related https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/305590/api-cache-behavior-can-be-exploited-to-hide-posts-from-api-clients last night. Don't have an ETA (I'm just the on-call SRE right now), but it is being worked on. CC @quartata

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This *should* be addressed as part of [this change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/305590/api-cache-behavior-can-be-exploited-to-hide-posts-from-api-clients).

Aside for that fix, there have been no intentional changes to the API's caching logic.  It is intended that new content appears relatively quickly in the API.

Let me know if the issue still presents itself, and I'll dive back in.